# Does liberating FND bases and checkpoints provide any benefits beyond access to the bases and the item/reagent rewards for liberating them?

Tags: far-cry-6

I'm playing Far Cry 6 and I've done all Operations in Madraguda, El Este and Valle de Oro, as well as the first two Operations in Esperanza,

> The one in the Hotel where you first meet Diego and the one where Dani gets captured and almost killed by General Raul.

I've also liberated some of the bases and checkpoints and done some of the Yaran Stories and Treasure Hunts, but not all of them. I'm wondering whether there are any less direct benefits to completing these side activities beyond the immediate rewards that you get for completing the objective. I know you can get weapons and equipment from them as well as Pesos and crafting reagents, but I don't have any real use for these because I simply cheated a bunch of crafting reagents and have a pretty decent set of weapons and equipment that can deal with just about anything that gets thrown at me easily besides tanks and armored helicopters. I also know that conquered bases serve as fast travel points and often have vehicle spawn points and workbenches, and those are nice but don't really help in combat.

What I'm more interested in would be things like additional Guerrillas being spawned around mission areas to help me fight, or a reduced FND presence in various areas, or fewer elite troops and armored vehicles, or permanent buffs to Dani that don't depend on the items I'm currently wearing. Those things feel like a tangible reason to actually do these areas that stays relevant throughout the game regardless of how good the items I have or can get are.

Are there any such bonuses from completing these side activities?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, I haven't noticed anything like that, in that like  more guerrillas showing up, etc.  I think besides the immediate rewards, they are mainly there for fast travel.